# Azure Automation Hybrid-Worker Get-AutomationPSCredential for PowerShell 7

Tags: azure, azure-automation, powershell-7.0

We are moving a few Azure Automation Hybrid-worker scripts to PowerShell 7.1.  In doing so one of the commands that work in PowerShell 5.1 is: `[PSCredential] $AutomationCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'abcdef'`.  When we try the same command in PowerShell 7.1 we get an error `The 'Get-AutomationPSCredential' command was found in the module 'Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets'`

We have added the Import-Module to the code but we get `Could not load file or assembly 'JobRuntimeData.Client, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified`.

We do find Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets the on the hybrid-worker, in the sandbox area.  We know that this module is loaded when the hybrid-worker is installed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#internal-cmdlets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are assuming the `Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets` is bugged at this point, but have not found anything to say that it is.  To get around it we were going to use a runbook variable to store the password, but it needs the cmdlet to actually decode a secret/hidden value.

In the end, we used a key vault to store the password.  The following is what was used as a workaround.

```
$User = "AutomationUser"
$KeyVaultName = "KeyVault"
try {
    $Password = (ConvertTo-SecureString (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Name $User -AsPlainText) -AsPlainText -Force)
    [PSCredential] $AutomationCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $Password)
}
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = "Unable to retrieve credentials for user: [${$User}].  $_"
    throw $ErrorMessage
    BREAK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationcredential?view=azps-6.6.0)

The `'Get-AutomationPSCredential` is currently supported till `Azure powershell 6.6.0`

[image]

**NOTE**: Powershell 7.1 is still in preview so this may be the reason for the error .

Please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-az-modules) for more information.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the usage?  I am trying to get the [PSCredential] out and the command that is referenced returns [CredentialInfo] and it does not contain the [PSCredential] for use later in the program.  You may be correct it is a problem with the preview.  For some reason, it does not like the import of the Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets.

Comment: So more investigation.  It seems like the Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets is bugged.  We have two separate Hybrid Workers and both have the same issue.   We tested to see if it was a [PSCredential] issue as we found a reference where if it was a parameter it would not work, but as a variable (we tested), it worked.

Comment: Thanks @David Thoma, For the kind information.

Comment: I agree with @AjayKumarGhose this seems to not work in 7.1 on a hybrid worker, but works on 5.1

Comment: Get-AzAutomationCredential is not the same as Get-AutomationPSCredential. The former is simply returning the information about the credential, not the actual credential. Get-AutomationPSCredential does return a PowerShell Credential - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials?tabs=azure-powershell#get-a-credential-asset.

Comment: Get-AutomationPSCredential is part of the internal cmdlet Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets and is loaded on every Hybrid Runbook Worker. As I understand it's not supported beyond PowerShell 5.1. Therefore I would assume the Key Vault solution is the only way to go. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#internal-cmdlets